# SumConvergence and Interval of Convergence

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

Consider the series: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(x-3)^n}{n}$$ Doing hand-calculations, I applied the Ratio Test and found that it converges if $|x-3|<1$, making the radius of convergence $R=1$.

Next, I used hand-calculations to test the endpoints. Substituting $x=2$, the series becomes
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2-3)^n}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n},$$
which is an alternating series that converges. Substituting $x=4$, the series becomes
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(4-3)^n}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n},$$
which is a harmonic series that diverges. Therefore, the interval of convergence is $[2,4)$.

To check my answer, I used:

```
SumConvergence[(x - 3)^n/n, n]
```

Which returns:

```
Abs[-3 + x] <= 1 && x != 4
```

Which agrees with all of my hand-calculations. I got pretty excited about this, as this would really help my students check their work. I was thinking it will not only give the radius of convergence, but check the endpoints.

But then I examined the series $$\sum\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n}}$$

My hand-calculations returned that the series converges if $|x|<1$. I then checked the endpoints of the interval and was able to determine convergence at $x=-1$, but divergence at $x=1$, making the interval of convergence $[-1,1)$. I then tried to check my answer with SumConvergence. The command

```
SumConvergence[x^n/Sqrt[n], n]
```

returned:

```
Abs[x] < 1
```

But then I tried

```
SumConvergence[(-1)^n/Sqrt[n], n]
```

which returned:

```
True
```

And I tried

```
SumConvergence[(1)^n/Sqrt[n], n]
```

which returned:

```
False
```

I am using Mathematica 11.1.0.0. So, my question, how come

```
SumConvergence[x^n/Sqrt[n], n]
```

did not return

Abs[x] < 1 && x != 1

especially since `SumConvergence[(-1)^n/Sqrt[n], n]` returned "True" and `SumConvergence[(1)^n/Sqrt[n], n]` returned "False."

**Additional example to show it is not just a square root problem:**

```
SumConvergence[((-1)^(n - 1) x^n)/n^3, n]
```

Returns:

```
Abs[x] < 1
```

It should be:

```
Abs[x] <= 1
```

Because `SumConvergence[((-1)^(n - 1) (-1)^n)/n^3, n]` and `SumConvergence[((-1)^(n - 1) (1)^n)/n^3, n]` both return "True."

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the expected result, shouldn't it be `Abs[x] < 1 && x ==-1`?

Comment: @AnjanKumar I was emulating this return above: `Abs[-3 + x] <= 1 && x != 4`

Comment: When I run `SumConvergence[x^n/n, n]` it returns correct result, whereas, 
`SumConvergence[x^n/Sqrt[n^2], n]` returns `Abs[x] < 1`. May be it has got something to do with `Sqrt`. This looks like a bug.

Comment: @AnjanKumar See my example in my update. Probably not just a square root problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the question is -- whether it's, "Does `SumConvergence` return only generically true results like some other solvers?", or "Is this a bug?" -- but in V11.2, we get correct and complete results:

```
SumConvergence[(x - 3)^n/n, n]
(*  Abs[-3 + x] <= 1 && x != 4  *)

SumConvergence[x^n/Sqrt[n], n]
(*  Abs[x] < 1 || x == -1  *)

SumConvergence[((-1)^(n - 1) x^n)/n^3, n]
(*  Abs[x] < 1 || x == 1 || x == -1  *)
```